# Converting HTMLCanvasElement to a object

Tags: javascript, image, reactjs, html5-canvas, filereader

I'm using a image cropper library to crop an image. I want to upload the cropped image using a function i have written. The issue is the image cropper returns the cropped image as `HTMLCanvasElement` . i want to convert it to a `object` to use in my function. I have tried passing a image file taken using `FileReader` to my function and it's working perfectly. The issue i''m facing is when trying to pass the cropped image which is a HTMLCanvasElement. How can i solve this?

This is the cropper library i'm using

https://github.com/mosch/react-avatar-editor

This is the function which i get the cropped image.

```
handleSave = () => {

    const img = this.editor.getImage();

    console.log("Type of image "+typeof img);

    this.props.croppedImage(img);


}
```

In my second component i'm accessing the `croppedImage` function

```
<CropperTest croppedImage={this.getCroppedImg}/>
```

getCroppedImg function

```
  getCroppedImg(img) {

        console.log("typeofNEW"+typeof event,img);

        this.props.onImageImgPoll(img);

    }
```

From here i'm passing the cropped image to a function called `onImageImgPoll` which is in another component

```
  onImageImgPoll(event) {

        this.setState({

            croppedImage:event

        })

        let array = this.state.filepoll.slice();
        let unq_file = event;

            let reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onloadend = (e) => {

                array.push(unq_file);
            };


    }
```

And the files i'm passing to the array should get uploaded using other functions. But in this case it won't happen because the passed image is in the form of `HTMLCanvasElement` . How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can save it as data url and then use it again in another function.
Btw. You cannot upload via javascript. You can do it with this function via ajax (base64 string) and then upload it by php for example.

```
canvas.toDataURL();
```